# Can I make a shortcut to specify a switched tab in Mac OSX Terminal?

Tags: macos, tabs, terminal, osx-mavericks, shortcut

In Chrome, it's possible to switch tabs with cmd + tab_number, like cmd + 3 to go to the third tab. Is there anyway to specify this for Terminal on a Mac running Mavericks?

I know how to change a shortcut via System Preferences, but I'm not the exact name of the Menu Command I should add, if it's even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Shift + Command + Left or Right Arrow to cycle through tabs:

<kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>←</kbd><kbd>→</kbd>

or

<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>{</kbd><kbd>}</kbd>

If you want to use a specific # as you mentioned then you'll have to script it or use windows instead of tabs.